# Improve long running EF query with AsNoTracking

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework v6.1.3 and one query is tacking > 10s to run from my application. It takes < 1s when adding AsNoTracking() to the call:

```
    public IList<Job> GetByERPHeaderIds(string[] headerIds)
    {
        return base.Query()
            .Include(j => j.PreferredBranch)
            .Include(j => j.JobType)
            .Include(j => j.Technicians)
            .Include(j => j.GmcJobStates)
            .Where(j => headerIds.Contains(j.ERPServiceOrderId))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
    }
```

The GetByERPHeaderIds() method gets an array with 400 elements. The problem is that I need to save back to the database after modify some items retrieved by the query. Down to my context I use the following code to manage the entities state:

```
    public virtual void Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (_context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            if (entity.IsNew)
            {
                _dbSet.Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                var cachedEntity = _dbSet.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(entity));

                if (cachedEntity != null)
                    _context.Entry(cachedEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;

                _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        if (!_context.IsUnitOfWorkActive)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

When I get the "Modified" state entity sometimes I get a DbUpdateException or sometimes I get duplicated entries

> ex.InnerException.InnerException  {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_dbo.TechnicianJob'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.TechnicianJob'. The duplicate key value is (1039, 239).\r\nThe
>   statement has been terminated."}  System.Exception
>   {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

---

**UPDATE1** :
In this example I'm trying to save a "Job" entity back to the database. This entity contains references to other tables, in this case, a reference to the table "TechnicianJob". It looks like when a detached entity is retrieved from the database, this is not retrieved with its table dependencies properly. I think this is why I'm getting that exception, because is trying to save an entity which is already in the database.

---

**UPDATE2** : 
This is how it looks my Repository after reading this [article](http://blog.maskalik.com/entity-framework/2013/12/23/entity-framework-updating-database-from-detached-objects/):

```
    public virtual void Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (_context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            if (entity.IsNew)
            {
                _dbSet.Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                var cachedEntity = _dbSet.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(entity));

                if (cachedEntity != null)
                {
                    var cachedEntry = _context.Entry(cachedEntity);
                    cachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                }
                else
                {
                    var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        if (!_context.IsUnitOfWorkActive)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generic save method, depends on changetracking. Or at least that the entities are in correct state.

I suggest you attach the Job entities before modifing them and calling Save()

```
context.Jobs.Attach(job);
```

Comment: That might be possible as well. Please see my updates. Not sure why is updating one entity (Job) and inserting other (TechnicianJob) but the EntitySate should be the reason

Comment: I suggest you attach the Job entities before modifing them and calling Save()

`context.Jobs.Attach(job);`

Comment: I don't think the problem is on attaching the entity. EF is performing a saving operation. The problem is on the related entity "TechnicianJob", which is trying to save and it's already in the database.

Answer (score 0):

**The trip**
To get the solution I made a bit of research. I found out by using "*AsNoTracking*" EF performs very good. On the other side your entities are no tracked anymore, which shouldn't be a big deal unless those entities have relations to other tables (my situation). I was able to reattach the entities (ie. *Job*) to the context by setting their status to "Modified". Then EF knows it has to make an update on that entity. What EF doesn't know is what to do with the related entities (ie. *TechnicianJob*). It keeps trying to insert them and you end up with duplicated key exceptions and multiple incorrect assignments.

**My solution**
I found a solution for my issue. I removed eager loading from my repository so I don't force EF to track the status of 4 different relations to other tables in one query. That boosted the performance from 10s to 100ms.

**Global solution**
It looks like the non-tracked entities is something will be solved in EF7 but until that is released... GraphDiff: It seems that this nuget package gives really good results in order to solve this inconvenience:

- Take a look at this blog describing the problem and how to implement a solution with GraphDiff:

  - http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/
- Nuget package GraphDiff:

  - https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff